# Apache subdomain directory to external server

Tags: linux, apache2, subdomain

I want a directory of one subdomain to be served by other external server without changing the url in browser.

```
Abc.server.com/directory
```

Directory part has to be served by different external server. Wondering how it would be achievable.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like a redirect?
Use can use Apache's **mod_rewrite**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.:]+\.)*abc\.server\.com\.directory\.?(:[0-9]*)?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.external.server.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can also use an **iframe**:

```
<iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="http://www.external.server.com/">
</iframe>
```

You can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection#HTTP_status_codes_3xx

Comment: Does it change url in browser too?

Comment: Well, the redirect yes, the iframe not.

Comment: Awesome will give it a go tonight and accept your answer should it work

Comment: Tried optionz one change link other Iframe is giving css error. Wonder if there is amyother optio

Comment: What error are you getting? Do you need to style the iframe?